# Cannot set property of UIImageView subclass

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

I've subclassed UIImageView, it's called ACCascadeImageView.

```
@interface ACCascadeImageView : UIImageView{
    BOOL isSpotlight;
}

@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL isSpotlight;

-----

@implementation ACCascadeImageView
@synthesize isSpotlight;
```

I then create instances like so, and add a gesturerecognizer..

```
ACCascadeImageView *imageview = 
    [[ACCascadeImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageframe];

UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];

[imageview addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

In the handleSingleTap method, I loop through my UIScollView subviews, and I try to do this for each one...

```
(imageview in this scope is [gestureRecognizer view])
[imageview setIsSpotlight:NO];
```

But I get this...

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[UIImageView setIsSpotlight:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6888be0'
```

Why has my `ACCascadeImageView` suddenly become `UIImageView`? I apologize if I'm doing something stupid, but I've subclassed `UIImageView` before just fine. I'm confused.

I should say that I've `NSLog'd [imageview class]` and I get, "`ACCascadeImageView`".

Here's the problem:

```
NSArray *cascadeImages = [PhotoCascade subviews];
for (ACCascadeImageView *v in cascadeImages){
    NSLog(@"RESPONDS: %d", [v respondsToSelector:@selector(setIsSpotlight:)]);
    [v setIsSpotlight:NO];
}
```

I get :
RESPONDS: 1
RESPONDS: 0

Then it dies.

Comment: Please show the `initWithFrame` method of your `ACCascadeImageView`.

Comment: here's the initWithFrame
`
    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {
        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) {
            // Initialization code
        }
        return self;
    }
`

It's the generic one that Xcode puts in when you subclass UIImageView.

Comment: If you `NSLog(@"%d", [gestureView respondsToSelector:@selector(setIsSpotlight:)]);`, what does it say?

Comment: can you show whole code where you are calling `[imageview setIsSpotlight:NO];
` and can you use `imageview.isSpotlight = NO;` and see if compiler is throwing some error/warnings???

Comment: @InderKumarRathore I call it right after adding the gesture.

Comment: @BrendenEllingboe that looks strange. Anyway please edit your question and place the code at its exact position.

Comment: @Rob wait a minute. It's not the gestureView object that kills it, I loop through the UIScrollView subviews, all of which are EXPLICITLY ACCascadeImageView (created with the same code above) and THEY cannot call setIsSpotlight. Let me look

Comment: @Rob I just do [PhotoCascade addSubview:imageview]; after ading the gesture recognizer with the code above ^. I NSLog'd the subviews and there's always 1 rogue UIImageView amongst all my ACCascadeImageViews. WTF?

Comment: I'd start counting the ACCascadeImageView's that I'm adding versus what's being returned by the `subviews` collection and see if the problem with one of the images you added to your `NSMutableArray` or see if there's something else there (e.g. some graphical element like a button or something)? Maybe set your `tag` property of the ACCascadeImageView's as you add them, then as you iterate through your `subviews`, check out the tags and identify the offending image. I bet the offending subview is something other than one of the ACCascadeImageView's images you added.

Answer (score 0):

You can't be sure `[gestureRecognizer view]` is your `UIImageView`. To check this try `NSLog(@"view: %@", [gestureRecognizer.view class]);`. My tests says it's just `UIView`.
If you're adding gesture recognizer to your image view the selector will be fired only when the user taps this view. So you could omit those checks at all.

Comment: I (think) actually can be sure, with how I'm doing it. All my tests give me the expected result. I just ran your suggestion, and I got this..

view: ACCascadeImageView

Comment: Yep, misunderstood the question. I taught you're trying to use recognizer's `view` property.

Comment: I am... 

ACCascadeImageView *gestureView = [gestureRecognizer view];

then doing [gestureView class] gives me the same as above ^

Comment: I add it to a UIScrollView, and it shows up just fine, and the tap events fired, but dies when I try to do anything with isSpotlight.

Comment: Well, try to log actual `gestureRecognizer.view` - it'll be `UIView`. Your assignment overrides object's class but does nothing more.

Comment: I did just that, and got this... 


view: <ACCascadeImageView: 0x6ef7a20; baseClass = UIImageView; frame = (160 320; 80 80); alpha = 0.9; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6ef7910>>

Comment: Hmm.. Try to set isSpotlight property right after image view creation and see if there'll be crash.

Comment: It's created in another part of the code (same view controller) and I actually do call [imageview setIsSpotlight:NO]; and it works just fine. It only fails in the gesture method I've added in the original post ^

Comment: Very strange.. Try to make your imageView as a property and work with this. Just to be sure it's not accidentally released somewhere and in order to exclude the possibility of object corruption during pass through gesture recogniser engine.

Comment: Or maybe it want direct cast `ACCascadeImageView *gestureView = (ACCascadeImageView *)[gestureRecognizer view];` :)

Comment: That didn't change anything.. =(

Answer (score 0):

You're saying that your `handleSingleTap` is returning TRUE in response to `respondsToSelector:@selector(setIsSpotlight:)`, but then when you try to use `setIsSpotlight`, it fails? That is a mystery.

For example, I've created this super simple example, and it works as you'd expect:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface Test : UIImageView

@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL isSpotlight;

@end

@implementation Test

@synthesize isSpotlight;

@end

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Test *test = [[Test alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:test];
    test.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    [test addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    Test *imageview = (Test *)[sender view];

    NSLog(@"%s %d", __FUNCTION__, [imageview respondsToSelector:@selector(setIsSpotlight:)]);

    [imageview setIsSpotlight:NO];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

The problem has to be something simple, but with limited code snippets provided in your question, it's not obvious what the problem is. But the code you've provided above would not manifest the sort of problem you describe. There must be some rogue `UIImageView` in your app!

Comment: Somehow [PhotoCascade subviews] has 1 UIImageView among my subclasses.. it's always the 2nd view, but it doesn't make sense. They're all created the same.

Comment: @BrendenEllingboe Perhaps an image view that was added (and forgotten about) in Interface Builder? Some other graphical element?

Comment: Otherwise, set some track able property (`tag`?) as you add your custom images and you can track down which is the offending one.

Comment: Just did a bunch of stuff. I logged the subviews before I even add my own, and there's a rogue UIImageView somewhere, but it's not in Interface Builder anywhere, and I never create an explicit UIImageView anywhere. hmmm, well I found the problem, just where is it coming from?

Comment: @BrendenEllingboe Without the code, it's hard to say, but if you're confident it's not in IB, then I can only suggest searching your code for all occurrences of `UIImageView` and see if you can find it. Or maybe write code that says `if (![imageview isKindOfClass:[ACCascadeImageView class]]) { //write the image to Documents folder }` and then look at the image and see if you can figure out what it is. Assuming, of course, that the imageview has an image! Or (less elegant) just have your code check for `respondsToSelector` or `isKindOfClass` and ignore the image if it's not one of yours.

Comment: Needless to say, the image view obviously has to be something that was created (either accidentally or consciously for reasons since forgotten) or is in IB. There are no situations that I know of that would cause an image view to be created automatically. I'm surprised your code is assigning the gesture recognizer to it, though! Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: Yeah... it has an image. Here it is: http://cdn.piculo.us/gk5N79438c275b3ee71f3133ca83b3715351.png I don't have ANYTHING like that in my project. and when I click on it, it fades out, but I haven't implemented a single animation.. so, I'm just as confused before.

Comment: It's not square, so it's clearly some constructed image. Very, very strange. Are you using any third party libraries (like some banner ad library or something like that)? Until you track it down, just use `isKindOfClass` to make sure you ignore this offending image. (Frankly, I never rely on iterating through `subviews` without checking the subview type or tag, because later in life you may add some other element to the view and the code will break if you don't do this anyway.) But I'd personally really want to figure out what's creating this image for me. Good luck!

Comment: I'm using MBProgressHUD in the view, but it's not attached to the UIScrollView so why would it be inside it? So weird

Answer (score 0):

By your results, and since you only test once per object, it seems the first object in the array is your custom subview, but the second is not. Maybe somehow one of the objects in *cascadeImages* isn't an ACCascadeImageView. Step through the array and perform introspection on each one, logging the results, to make sure the array only contains ACCascadeImageViews.

Comment: Yeah, currently doing that now, I'll report back.

Comment: Update: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241321/cannot-set-property-of-uiimageview-subclass#comment16408158_12241705

Comment: Have you overriden addSubview:, performed introspection on subviews as they're added, and logged their types? That way, you know exactly when the rogue view is added.